# How to create comma-formatted number from macro output value?

Tags: macros, numbering

In the following document I would like for the numbers to have a thousandths separator comma.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}
\begin{document}

\newtotcounter{fund}
\newcommand{\fund}[1]{\addtocounter{fund}{#1}#1}

In total, my funding was \$\total{fund}.

My first funding was worth \$\fund{3000}.

My second funding was worth \$\fund{50000}.

\end{document}
```

I have tried the `sistyle` and `siunitx` packages in the Preamble, but to no avail.

```
\usepackage{sistyle}
    \SIthousandsep{,}
```

or

```
\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
```

How can I get a comma between these values that won't break the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution to the Updated Question**

The question was updated after I posted my answer. Here is the solution to the updated one. This uses the `refcount`
package.

You need to save the total in a label whenever you wish and then use this
whenever you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}

\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\def\refcounter#1{%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel
  {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{fund}
\def\fund#1{\addtocounter{fund}{#1}\$\num{#1}}
\def\SaveTotal#1#2{\refcounter{#1}\label{#2}}
\newcounter{showtotal}
\def\ShowTotal#1{\setcounterref{showtotal}{#1}\${\num{\arabic{showtotal}}}}

\begin{document}

After the second one, my total funding was \ShowTotal{totalOne}.

And my third and fourth funding made my total funding  \ShowTotal{totalTwo}.

My first funding was worth \fund{3000}.

My second funding was worth \fund{50000}.

\SaveTotal{fund}{totalOne}

Then, I got a third funding of \fund{150000}.

And finally got a fourth funding of \fund{50000000}.

\SaveTotal{fund}{totalTwo}

\end{document}
```

**The Updated Output**

[image]

---

**Solution to the Original Question**

**The Basics**

Merely using the `siunitx` package does not ensure (it should not) that all your numbers are automatically formatted.
You need to explicitly call the `\num` command in order to have a number formatted.

So, I modified your `\fund` command little, and defined the `\Total` command to display the counter value.

(I took the liberty of putting in the $ symbol inside the macros.)

**The Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}

\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\newtotcounter{fund}
\newcommand{\fund}[1]{\addtocounter{fund}{#1}\$\num{#1}}
\def\Total#1{\$\num{\arabic{#1}}}

My first funding was worth \fund{3000}.

My second funding was worth \fund{50000}.

Thus, in total, my funding was \Total{fund}.

\end{document}
```

**The Output**

[image]

Comment: I've updated my question with one key difference. The total should be first. In order to get the total first, I'm using the `totcount` package. It seems your `\def\Total#1{\$\num{\arabic{#1}}}` breaks the behavior of the total line when it is placed above the first and second funding lines.

Comment: @CephBirk Yes, it should. The total value is being updated by the `totcount` package in the  `fund` counter. When used first, the counter is yet to be set and has a value zero.

Comment: @CephBirk I am not saying that what you are asking for is not doable. But your original question was about comma separating numbers which has already been addressed by my answer. Now, you have edited your original question to something like printing a future value in counter.

Comment: @CephBirk See the updated answer.

Comment: I apologize for the added challenge, but thanks for rising to the occasion.

Comment: @CephBirk That gave me the opportunity to write two answers. Everything has got a bright side. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own [`totcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/totcount)-like setup using `\label`-`\ref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator={,}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newtotcounter}[1]{%
  \newcounter{tot:#1}% Create new counter
  \g@addto@macro\@enddocumenthook{% ~ \AtEndDocument...
    \def\@currentlabel{\protect\num{\arabic{tot:#1}}}% ... update \@currentlabel and ...
    \label{tot:#1}}}% ... mark with \label.
\makeatother

\newtotcounter{fund}

\newcommand{\fund}[1]{\addtocounter{tot:fund}{#1}\$\num{#1}}% Increment tot:fund counter
\newcommand{\total}[1]{\$\ref{tot:#1}}% Recall tot:#1 \label

\begin{document}

In total, my funding was \total{fund}.

My first funding was worth \fund{3000}.

My second funding was worth \fund{50000}.

\end{document}
```